# Rollup multiple rows into one

Tags: mysql, pivot

I would like to preface this by saying that I'm relatively new to writing SQL. Please bear with my stupidity.

I'm trying to extract data from multiple tables onto a spreadsheet

I have 3 tables that look like so.

`Account`

| id | name | is_setup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Acc1 | 1 |

`Profile`

| id | account_id(fk) | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | profname | shopify |

`ProfilePreferences`

| id | profile_id(fk) | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | is_quote_enabled | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | auto_sync | 1 |

I have a query that returns what I want but I can't wrap my head around how to get results in the same row rather than them being presented as 2 rows for the settings in the preferences table.

My query looks like so...

```
SELECT acc.name,
       prof.`integration_type`,
       prof.`name`,
       prof.`status`,
       acc.`is_setup`,
       prof.pref_name,
       prof.`pref_value`,
       sh_acc_id,
       sid
FROM accounts acc
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT prof.account_id AS pid,
            prof.`integration_type`,
            prof.`name`,
            prof.`status`,
            prof_pref.`name` AS pref_name,
            prof_pref.`value` AS pref_value
     FROM profiles prof
     INNER JOIN profile_preferences prof_pref ON prof.`id` = prof_pref.`profile_id`
     AND prof.`integration_type`="shopify"
     WHERE prof_pref.`name`="is_quote_enabled"
         AND prof_pref.`value`= 1
         OR prof_pref.`name`="auto_sync"
         AND prof_pref.`value`= 1
         OR prof_pref.`name`="is_quote_enabled"
         AND prof_pref.`value`= 0
         OR prof_pref.`name`="auto_sync"
         AND prof_pref.`value`= 0) prof ON acc.`id` = pid
WHERE acc.`is_setup` = 1;
```

The output I get looks like so...

| name | integration_type | name | status | is_setup | pref_name | pref_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acc1 | shopify | profname | 1 | 1 | auto_sync | 1 |
| Acc1 | shopify | profname | 1 | 1 | is_quote_enabled | 1 |

Is there a way to output something like this:

| name | integration_type | name | status | is_setup | auto_sync | is_quote_enabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acc1 | shopify | profname | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: The keyword to search for is "pivot"

Comment: @mustaccio can you give me a simple example of how I can use pivot for my use-case?

Comment: @mustaccio I tried doing the following in my outer most select statement **SELECT acc.name,
       prof.`integration_type`,
       prof.`name`,
       prof.`status`,
       acc.`is_setup`,
       CASE when pref_name="auto_sync" THEN pref_value AS is_auto_sync_enabled,
       prof.`pref_value`,
       sh_acc_id,
       sid
FROM accounts acc**.... but I get an error saying there is a syntax error, can you point me towards what Im doing wrong here?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS is_auto_sync_enabled,
       CASE when prof.pref_name="is_quote_enabled" ' at line 6` this is the error i get

Comment: Check the `CASE` expression syntax.

Comment: @mustaccio really appreaciate your efforts on this one please see below my answer and let me know if there is something I can improve upon. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mustaccio I was finally able to re-factor the query to output exactly what I wanted

The `CASE` syntax was incorrect and I was missing the `END` clause

This is the final query I ran

```
SELECT acc.`id`,
       acc.`name`,
       acc.`created_at`,
       acc.`is_setup`,
       SUM(CASE prof.pref_name
               WHEN 'auto_sync' THEN prof.`pref_value`
               ELSE 0
           END) AS `auto_sync`,
       SUM(CASE prof.pref_name
               WHEN 'is_quote_enabled' THEN prof.`pref_value`
               ELSE 0
           END) AS `is_quote_enabled`
FROM accounts acc
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT prof.account_id AS profile_account_id,
            prof.`integration_type`,
            prof_pref.`name` AS pref_name,
            prof_pref.`value` AS pref_value
     FROM profiles prof
     INNER JOIN profile_preferences prof_pref ON prof.`id` = prof_pref.`profile_id`
     AND prof.`integration_type`="shopify"
     WHERE prof_pref.`name`="is_quote_enabled"
         AND prof_pref.`value`= 1
         OR prof_pref.`name`="auto_sync"
         AND prof_pref.`value`= 1
         OR prof_pref.`name`="is_quote_enabled"
         AND prof_pref.`value`= 0
         OR prof_pref.`name`="auto_sync"
         AND prof_pref.`value`= 0) prof ON acc.`id` = profile_account_id
WHERE acc.`is_setup` = 1
GROUP BY `acc`.`id`,
         `acc`.`name`,
         `acc`.`created_at`,
         `acc`.`is_setup`;
```

Now the output produced looks like so...

| id | name | created_at | is_setup | auto_sync | is_quote_enabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | 2021-12-09 | 1 | 1 | 1 |